# How to use Aether in a org.apache.maven.AbstractMavenLifecycleParticipant

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, aether

I followed this example to get the required dependencies injected into my AbtractMavenLifecyleParticipant:

- http://www.sonatype.com/people/2011/01/how-to-use-aether-in-maven-plugins/
- http://maven.apache.org/examples/maven-3-lifecycle-extensions.html

The 'afterProjectsRead' get called perfectly, but repoSystem, repoSession and remoteRepos where always 'null'.

How can I get hold on these objects from within a AbstractMavenLifecyleParticipant?

```
import org.apache.maven.AbstractMavenLifecycleParticipant;
import org.apache.maven.MavenExecutionException;
import org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession;
import org.codehaus.plexus.component.annotations.Component;
import org.sonatype.aether.RepositorySystem;
import org.sonatype.aether.RepositorySystemSession;
import org.sonatype.aether.repository.RemoteRepository;

@Component(role = AbstractMavenLifecycleParticipant.class, hint = "skipper")
public class ModuleSkipperLifecycleParticipant extends AbstractMavenLifecycleParticipant {

    /**
     * @component
     */
    private RepositorySystem repoSystem;

    /**
     * @parameter default-value="${repositorySystemSession}"
     * @readonly
     */
    private RepositorySystemSession repoSession;

    /**
     * @parameter default-value="${project.remotePluginRepositories}"
     * @readonly
     */
    private List<RemoteRepository> remoteRepos;

    @Override
    public void afterProjectsRead(MavenSession session) throws MavenExecutionException {
        super.afterProjectsRead(session);

        System.out.println("repoSession: " + repoSession);
        System.out.println("repoSystem: " + repoSystem);
        System.out.println("remoteRepos: " + remoteRepos);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how we do it in [jcabi-aether](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-aether/):

```
final File repo = this.session.getLocalRepository().getBasedir();
final Collection<Artifact> deps = new Aether(this.getProject(), repo).resolve(
  new DefaultArtifact("junit", "junit-dep", "", "jar", "4.10"),
  JavaScopes.RUNTIME
);
```

Maybe you can just use the library, instead of writing it yourself..

Comment: that looks great, the first test seems to work - I'll give it a more detailed testing. Many thanks for now!!!!!

Comment: although I'm not gona use this library, it gave me the right hints - thanks!